# Show that $I=\{(0,0,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: -1\leq t \leq 1\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y=\{(x,0,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2 + z^2 = 1 , z\geq 0\} $

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I have been able to show homeomorphism between first and the second one, except for the condition $z=0$. I may have complicated too much my answer, but here's the function I invented:

$f(x,y,z,t)= Rot_y(\frac{\pi}{2}*t).(0,e^{-z},1)$, where $Rot_y$ denotes rotation, with $y$ fixed.

Comment: The definition of $I$ is strange... you have $z$ in one hand and $t$ in the other one, with no relation between both.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I though that as well. I simply treated it as a 4th coordinate. I guess it's written that way because of my next exercise related to Rienmann sphere

Comment: You should clarify that. Also, the definition of $Y$ requires clarification. It is not very engaging to work on a question which looks fuzzy.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net sorry, my bad, it had a mistake

Comment: The definition of $I$ has a typo. $t$ has to be replaced by $z$. What is $t$ in $f(x,y,z,t)$?

Answer (score 1):

Let us first consider a slightly simpler case:
$$I' = [-1,1], $$
$$Y' = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2  \mid x^2 + y^2 = 1, y \ge 0 \} .$$
The projection $p : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, p(x,y) = x$,  restricts to
a map $p' : Y' \to I'$. This map is a homeomorphism; its inverse is given by $(p')^{-1}(t) = (t, \sqrt{1-t^2})$.

Obviously $I \approx I'$ and $Y \approx Y'$ which proves $I \approx Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Send $(0,0,z)$ to $(x'(z) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}z),0,z'(z) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}z))$. The idea is to think of $z$ as the (scaled) angle.

Comment: Doesn't that fail to be injective?

Comment: How so? It's true that cosine alone isn't injective on $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, but the additional information that sine provides should be enough to uniquely recover the point. I might actually be wrong, tho I doubt it, but if you find a point where this is not injective please let me know.